# Offline Notification in PhoneGap or Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I already have the ff:

index.html

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
}

function onOffline() {
    alert('device is offline');
}
```

body tag

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

Plugin:

```
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.12 "Network Information"
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Config.xml:

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

But the `offline` was not triggered. Do I missed something for this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

It looks like you can also use a `Toast`:

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/740

I've only ever done native dev, just found these via Google.